# Knockout does not find my template

Tags: knockout.js

Knockout does not find my template:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find template with ID response
```

What do I wrong? I have correctly defined the template.

**VIEW**

```
<script id="map" type="text/html">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:200px;background-color: green;width:100px;height:200px;" data-bind="text: streetName"></div>    
</script>

<script id="reponse" type="text/html">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:200px;background-color: red;width:100px;height:200px;" data-bind="text: alarmNumber">3333</div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: currentChildTemplate(), data: selectedListItem() }"></div>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
return function()
{
  var currentChildTemplate = ko.observable(response);
  var selectedListItem = ko.observable();

   return {
            currentChildTemplate: currentChildTemplate          
        };
}
```

Comment: have you notice your typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo :

response in the error

reponse in the html

Comment: arghhh... and I starred 2 times at it and I read it correctly... :S